# Python tkinter canvas custom user input program doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a simulator program on python 3 Tkinter window. The progress is now disrupt due to a bug in the input program I build myself.

The broken code that I'm working on right now:

```
import string
import tkinter as tk
text = "awdd"
doIt=True


def key_event(label, event):
    global doIt, text
    text = w.itemcget(label,"text")
    if doIt==False:
        return 1
    if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
        w.itemconfig(label, text=text[:-1])
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        w.itemconfig(label, text=text + ' ' )
    elif event.keysym == "Return":
        doIt=False
        password=text
        print ('PASSWORD:%s' % (password))
        print ('PROGRAM STOPPED')
    elif event.char in string.ascii_lowercase:
       # Character is an ASCII letter
        w.itemconfig(label, text = text + event.char)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    w = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
    w.pack()
    label = w.create_text(1,0, text=text, fill= 'green', anchor='nw', font=
('courier',13))

    w.tag_bind(label,"<Key>", lambda e: key_event(label,e))

    root.update()
    # See side note 2
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

So the program will check for input from the user as long as **doIt==True**. But when I run the program, the key_event() function doesn't do anything at all! Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please describe what the problem is in detail, the behavior you expect, or post the Error stack trace.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried adding print statements to a) make sure `key_event` is being called, and b) verify that `text` is what you think it is, and c) verify that `event.keysym` is what you think it is?

Comment: I have try the key_event out without a canvas, and it work perfectly well @Bryan Oakley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture input not from canvas, but from Tinker `root`, and to access `w` in `key_event`, you need to make it global. Full working code is as following:

```
import string
import tkinter as tk
text = "password: "
doIt=True
w = None


def key_event(label, event):
    global doIt, text
    text = w.itemcget(label,"text")
    if doIt==False:
        return 1
    if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
        w.itemconfig(label, text=text[:-1])
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        w.itemconfig(label, text=text + ' ' )
    elif event.keysym == "Return":
        doIt=False
        password=text
        print ('PASSWORD:%s' % (password))
        print ('PROGRAM STOPPED')
    elif event.char in string.ascii_lowercase:
       # Character is an ASCII letter
        w.itemconfig(label, text = text + event.char)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    global w
    w = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=200)
    w.pack()
    label = w.create_text(1,0, text=text, fill= 'green', anchor='nw', font=
('courier',13))

    # w.tag_bind(label,"<Key>", lambda e: key_event(label,e))
    root.bind('<Key>', lambda e: key_event(label,e))

    root.update()
    # See side note 2
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

Comment: Can you add a function to wait for the user to finish typing the password then print it on idle screens?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to capture keystrokes form canvas as canvas does not naturally get keyboard focus. You could do it with `w.focus_set()` but I'm not sure if it's even possible to give keyboard focus to a canvas widget...

Why not bind to root instead:

```
root.bind('<Key>', lambda e: key_event(label,e))
```